# How can I Extract values with information from big text file using php

Tags: php, text, preg-match, preg-match-all, preg-grep

I'm trying to get some data from text file, those data are repeated every random line

I'm trying to get this from text file, and there are alot of 2/6 blocks. i need to get them all, using aloop.

**Example data I need to get it**.

```
TRAFFIC MEASUREMENT REPORT PART     2/    6 VLR MEASUREMENT            VLRMEAS 

SAMPLE DATE:    FROM    2020-10-22 14:00:00:09
                TO      2020-10-22 15:00:00:13

REGISTERED SUBSCRIBERS:


LOCATION AREA CODE     CURRENT     AVERAGE        TMS1        TMS2        TMS3
       UNKNOWN LAC           2           2           0           0           0
               113       75868       75749           0           0           0
               115       40627       40732           0           0           0
              1102       70422       70489           0           0           0
              1105       87075       87067           0           0           0
              1117       56150       56180           0           0           0
              1118       67175       67444           0           0           0
              1120       74385       74381           0           0           0
              1121       65034       65060           0           0           0
              1122       21636       21407           0           0           0
              1217       22944       22856           0           0           0
              1218       49054       48993           0           0           0
              1318       24283       24066           0           0           0
              1418       16366       16350           0           0           0
              2118       17812       17674           0           0           0
              2120       79644       79489           0           0           0
TOTAL                   768477      767939           0           0           0

PART     2/    6
END OF REPORT
```

from big file (1/6 ,3/6 ect..).

I tried doing like this

```
    $lines = file($file,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    foreach ($lines as $line){
     if(strstr($line,'2/    6')){
         echo $line .'<br>';
     }elseif (preg_match('/(\w+)\s+(\d\end\:\report\d)\s+-->/', $line, $match)){
         print_r($match);
     }
    }
```

I get only one line from each block

```
TRAFFIC MEASUREMENT REPORT PART 2/ 6 VLR MEASUREMENT VLRMEAS
PART 2/ 6
TRAFFIC MEASUREMENT REPORT PART 2/ 6 VLR MEASUREMENT VLRMEAS
PART 2/ 6
TRAFFIC MEASUREMENT REPORT PART 2/ 6 VLR MEASUREMENT VLRMEAS
PART 2/ 6
TRAFFIC MEASUREMENT REPORT PART 2/ 6 VLR MEASUREMENT VLRMEAS
PART 2/ 6
```

I hope you get me well, I tried to find any answers but I couldn't find what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and a pattern like:

```
^.*\d/\h*\d.*(?:\R.*)*?\REND OF REPORT\b
```

Or use the exact digits in the pattern

```
^.*2/\h*6.*(?:\R.*)*?\REND OF REPORT\b
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*\d/\h*\d.*` Match a line with a digit `/` optional spaces and a digit, then the rest of the line
- `(?:\R.*)*?` Repeat as least lines as possible
- `\R` Match a newline
- `END OF REPORT\b` Match `END OF REPORT` and a word boundary to prevent a partial word match

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xsRQgy/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/oh1WR)

```
$file = "myfile.txt";
$str = file_get_contents($file);
$re = '`^.*\d/\h*\d.*(?:\R.*)*?\REND OF REPORT\b`m';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output will be an array with all the matched parts.

---

Or another variation:

```
^.*\d/\h*\d.*(?:\R(?!END OF REPORT).*)*\REND OF REPORT\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O8TeFo/1)

Comment: Its perfect but is till get other data such as 1/6 and 3/6 blocks, i need only 2/6 blocks from the text file

Comment: @user15584147 Then you could use the digits in the pattern `^.*2/\h*6.*(?:\R.*)*?\REND OF REPORT\b` See https://regex101.com/r/E6NOKw/1

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works but need to be styled, all comes in one line.

Comment: Wat do you mean by styled?

Comment: all data should be in table, so they can read them very clear, now all data in one line $match[0]

Comment: What do you mean by table? Can you give an example?

Comment: here what i get (TRAFFIC MEASUREMENT REPORT PART 2/ 6 VLR MEASUREMENT VLRMEAS SAMPLE DATE: FROM 2020-10-22 14:00:00:09 TO 2020-10-22 15:00:00:13 REGISTERED SUBSCRIBERS: LOCATION AREA CODE CURRENT AVERAGE TMS1 TMS2 TMS3 UNKNOWN LAC 2 2 0 0 0 113 75868 75749 ...

Comment: i want to make them organized same as the text file, separated on table <table>, each 2/6 has its own table

Comment: But this question is about getting the right data, not formatting the data right? You could split the entries in the array on a newline and then loop the separate lines to do the formatting.

Comment: its okay, that what i will do, thanks a lot